# Central subgroups .......

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

Have a question about the central subgroup.

E is an elation group.

Let $E_{x,y}$ be a stabilizer of points $x$ and $y$. Then the group $E_{x,y}$ is a central subgroup both $E_{x}$ and $E_{y}$, where $E_{x}, E_{y}$ are stabilizers of points $x$ and $y$ resply.

I got this problem one of the proof in an article. To prove the rest of the  theorem I need to this first.

Could you help me to prove this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is an "elation group?"

Comment: Elation group in geometry, comes from projective planes and Laguerre planes. Without considering the elation how do I prove this?

Comment: So how is it defined?

Comment: Can find the definition of a projective plane. This is the one for projective plane, but different from Laguerre planes.  A collineation of a projective plane is termed an elation if it has a center(i.e., a point such that every line through that point is preserved by the collineation) and an axis (i.e., a line such that every point on the line is preserved by the collineation) containing the center.